# Android: performance issue multiple textures Opengl ES

Tags: android, performance, textures, opengl-es-2.0

The game I made in android is based on a canvas, and for performance reason I am to lift this game to OpenGL ES instead.

The problem is still performance - I have a background and a sprite bouncing around the screen - this works very well but it seem to be the same performance issue as with using a Canvas. Now and then the sprite animation are not perfectly smooth. I guess my design is bad or really bad.

Is it wrong to call texImage2D for every frame? What are the alternatives to this?

Thanks!!!

```
 @Override
public void onDrawFrame(GL10 unused) {

    GLES20.glClear(GLES20.GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GLES20.GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    long speedFactor = 5000;
    long time = SystemClock.uptimeMillis() % speedFactor;
    float angleInDegrees = (360.0f / speedFactor) * ((int) time);

    GLES20.glUseProgram(mProgramHandle);

    mMVPMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_MVPMatrix");
    mMVMatrixHandle = GLES20.glGetUniformLocation(mProgramHandle, "u_MVMatrix");
    mColorHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Color");
    mNormalHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_Normal");
    mTextureCoordinateHandle = GLES20.glGetAttribLocation(mProgramHandle, "a_TexCoordinate");

    GLES20.glEnable(GLES20.GL_BLEND);
    GLES20.glBlendFunc(GLES20.GL_ONE, GLES20.GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);


    //BACKGROUND
    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, background, 0);
    //GLUtils.texSubImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, background);
    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, 0, 0.0f, -2.00001f);
    drawTriangle(mCubePositions);



    // THE MOVING SPRITE.
    int rest = 0;
    if (modulo > 0) {
        rest = frameCntr % modulo;
    }

    GLUtils.texImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, alien[bitmapIndex], 0);
    //GLUtils.texSubImage2D(GLES20.GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0, 0, 0, alien[bitmapIndex]);
    if (rest == 0) {
        bitmapIndex++;
    }

    if (bitmapIndex == alien.length) {
        bitmapIndex = 0;
    }

    frameCntr++;

    float deltaX = (motion.get_velocityX() * motion.get_xDirection());
    float deltaY = (motion.get_velocityY() * motion.get_yDirection());
    anim_x += deltaX;
    anim_y += deltaY;

    Matrix.setIdentityM(mModelMatrix, 0);
    Matrix.translateM(mModelMatrix, 0, anim_x, anim_y, -7f);
    //Matrix.rotateM(mModelMatrix, 0, angleInDegrees, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f);
    drawTriangle(mAlienPositions);
    calcPos();
    collision.collisionWalls(motion, xPos, yPos, game_width, game_height);
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, `GLUtils.texImage2D()` calls `glTexImage2D()`.

`glTexImage2D()`, on the other hand is used for loading the bitmap. You only need to call it once to load the texture. It loads the bitmap into the currently bound texture.

In the draw call you should bind to the needed texture by calling `GLES20.glBindTexture( target, texture )`. `target` is either `GL_TEXTURE_2D` or `GL_TEXTURE_CUBE_MAP`. `texture` is a texture name that was bound before calling `GLUtils.texImage2D()`.

Also, don't forget to unbind the current texture using `GLES20.glBindTexture( target, 0 )` after each draw call and after initialization.

Comment: thanks for answer - i will look into this and come back

Comment: Thanks for your answer - the performance seem to have increased a lot when using glBindTexture( ...) in the onDrawFrame instead of calling texImage2D all the time.

Comment: By the way - if you have time to answer, what is the implication of not unbinding the texture after each draw?

Comment: @java Well, it's not necessary but it may lead to unforseen consequences since OpenGL is a state machine; for example, when you are drawing an untextured object after a textured one using one shader for both. Not sure about the memory management for textures (could differ between implementations though) but this could also make more space for textures or other objects.